# Trying to open modal window when data row is clicked

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a script that open a modal window when a row is clicked in my table.
The table is produced using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data;
  $.get("get_timeline.php", function(data){
    //console.log("DATA", data);
  response = $.parseJSON(data);
  $(function() {
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
      var $tr = $('<tr class="TimeLineData" onclick="display("test");" >').append( // LINE 13
        $('<td>').text(item.deviceid),
        $('<td>').text(item.location),
        $('<td>').text(item.mediatype),
        $('<td>').text(item.campainname),
        $('<td>').text(item.medianame),
        $('<td>').text(item.start_date),
        $('<td>').text(item.end_date),
        $('<td>').text(item.uploadflag).toggleClass('flagclass', item.uploadflag === 1)
        ).appendTo('#records_table');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

On line 13 I have

```
 var $tr = $('<tr class="TimeLineData" onclick="display("test");" >').append(
```

And for the modal popup I have:

```
function display(test) {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
}
```

The error I am getting is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" in the console and "display(" in the source.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hey, it looks like you didn't escape the double quotes around "test", try var $tr = $('<tr class="TimeLineData" onclick="display(\"test\");" >').append(

Comment: @Frank A. Hi I already tried that but it made no difference, but thanks for your input.

Comment: I placed your code inside the console of Chrome and had no errors, and received back the row's text just fine.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson Hi in chrome console I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @DCJones I am using `Version 71.0.3578.98` of Chrome. Could you please post what you placed in your console window?

Comment: @Ryan Wilson My Chrome version is Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit). I did not place my code directly into the console, I ran the script from my server. Viewing the results in the console is where I see the error, as above.

Comment: I can place this in my console and get no errors: `var $tr = $('<tr class="TimeLineData" onclick="display("test");" >').append(
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1'),
        $('<td>').text('test1')
        );`